# Only display the first child of a div

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I've been struggling with finding a way to only display the first child of my div and hide all the rest. Can this be done purely in css or do I have to involve some Javascript?

So, how can I get this to only display first p-tag?

```
<div id="test1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8XYNx/

Comment: You could apply a class to the first element to keep your CSS simple.

Comment: Holy answer pile-up Batman.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/8XYNx/10/

CSS

```
  #test1 p{
    display:none;

}
#test1 p:first-child{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

A combination of `:not` and `first-child` should surely do it:

```css
#test1 p:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

Note that this won't work in IE before version 9.

Comment: You mean before version 9.

Answer (score 4):

By using `:first-child` wrapped in `:not()`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XYNx/6/)

```
#test1 p:not(:first-child) {
    display:none;
}
```

Note that `first-child` isn't supported by IE8 or earlier. If you want complete cross browser support, you will have to use Javascript.

A Javascript solution would be:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XYNx/13/)

```
var div = document.getElementById("test1");
var pList = div.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(var i=0; i<pList.length; i++) {
    if(pList[i] != div.children[0]) {
        pList[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#test1 p {
    display: none;
}
#test1 p:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child

Comment: The downside of this is that, in browsers that don't support `:first-child` (which admittedly isn't many) none of the `p` elements will display.

Comment: @lonesomeday true, but it is still more widely supported compared to :not

Comment: Indeed I was wrong---I misread the Quirksmode page. This will work in more browsers than mine will.

Answer (score 1):

By hiding all the P elements, and then implicitly displaying the first p element:

```
#test1 p {
    display: none;
}
#test1 p:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8XYNx/1/)

If a `DOCTYPE` is declared, this will work in IE7+. Check the browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) (unlike using `:not` which [will only work in IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) unless you use [IE7.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/))

Answer (score 1):

`display: none` on every element except the first (1n w/ 2 offset).

```
#test1 p:nth-child(1n + 2){
display: none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/8XYNx/11/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this, [should work with IE7+](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#t10)

CSS

```css
#test1>p ~ p{
    display: none;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/LtG3W/)

If you need older support then this should be cross-browser.

Javascript

```js
var test1 = document.getElementById("test1").getElementsByTagName("p"),
    i = 1,
    p = test1[i];

while (p) {
    p.style.display = "none";
    p = test1[i += 1];
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/W4f3M/)

Answer (score 1):

In your example you used only `p` elements, but if there are some other elemens included? In general, to show only the first element, you can use this:

```css
#test1 :not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

Notice this doesn't work in IE<9.

A [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dXvjX/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test1 p:not(:first-child)').hide();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/8XYNx/7/)

Comment: "JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language commonly used for client-side scripting. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript). Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this URL, use psudo element to select particular elements to apply CSS
http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: Uh, pseudo-elements are pseudo-elements. You can't use pseudo-element selectors to select elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#test1 p:not(:first-child)
{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```